# Grab substring after and before two specific characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, indexing, substring

i have a url search key like that:
?retailerKey=A and i want to grab the retailerKey substring. All examples that i saw are having as example how to take before the char with the indexOf example. How can i implement this to have this substring from the string ?retailerKey=A

Comment: I've read your question twice and still don't know what's your desired output. Could you clarify?

Comment: Besides that, what about using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `split()` the string on any `?` or `=` and take the middle item (`[1]`) from the outcome array.

```js
const data = "?retailerKey=A";
const result = data.split(/[\?=]/)[1];

console.log(result);
```

If you have multiple params, creating an object `fromEntries()` would be interesting.

```js
const data = "?retailerKey=A?otherKey=B";

const keyVals = data.split(/[\?=]/).filter(x => x); // keys and values
const result = Object.fromEntries(keyVals.reduce((acc, val, i) => {
  // create entries
  const chunkI = Math.floor(i / 2);
  if (!acc[chunkI]) acc[chunkI] = [];
  acc[chunkI].push(val);
  return acc;
}, []));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

use regex expression.
Following will return the value between character `?` and `=`

```js
var result =  "?retailerKey=A".match(/\?(.*)\=/).pop();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to always get the string between your query sign and equal sign `?ThisString=`
then you can simply use indexOf for example

```
str.slice(str.indexOf('?')+1,str.indexOf('='))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using library could be a better choice but to do it from scratch : I suggest to use split with a regular expression.

```
// split for char equals to ? or & or =;
const url = '/toto?titi=1&tata=2';
const args = url.split(/[\?\&\=]/);
// shift the first element of the list since it the base url before "?"
args.shift();

// detect malformed url
if (args.length % 2) {
    console.error('malformed url', args);
}

const dictArgs = {};

for (let i = 0; i < args.length /2; i ++) {
     const key = args[2*i];
     const val = args[2*i+1];
     dictArgs[key] = val;
}

console.log(dictArgs);
```